# Where is ng-init scoped to by default?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

If I have the following html:

```
<div ng-init="foo = 'bar'"></div>
```

And div is not contained in a controller, where is `foo` scoped to and how do I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ng-init` without any directive thats creates a child or isolated scope the property is bound to the `$rootScope`.

But you should not use `ng-init` in this way. See the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using ng-init in this case because I want to pass some data from the server to the client on the initial page load. I'm using jade's templating to embed it in the html.